# R: The standard errors are not reasonable when using mle together with pnorm

Tags: r, normal-distribution, standard-error, mle

The values in vector **a** are seen as the true values and I want to estimate them using mle. I make 100 "disturbed" vectors from **a** by adding noise, N(0,sigma^2). For every disturbed vector I sort them in decreasing order. Say that the observed order is: x_1>x_4>x_5>x_3>x_2 
We want to calculate the probability to observe this order and we do so by: P(X_1-X_4>0|a)*P(X_4-X_5>0|a)*P(X_5-X_3>0|a)*P(X_3-X_2>0|a) (we ignore the dependency), where X_1-X_4 ~ N(a[1]-a[4],2*std^2) and so on.

Usually when you use mle you use density function, but here we use pnorm. The problem I have after running the code below is that the standard errors are all the same (and way too large) for the estimates. What can I have done wrong?

**R-code:**

```
#library(stats4)
n <- 100
x <- mat.or.vec(n,5)
y <- mat.or.vec(n,5)
a <- c(100,100.5,100.75,100.7,100.25)                       
std <- sd(a)
Var <- std^2
for(i in 1:n){
    y[i,] <- a+rnorm(5,mean=0,sd=std)                       
    x[i,] <- sort(y[i,],decreasing = TRUE,index.return=TRUE)$ix
}                           

matris <- mat.or.vec(n,4)
sigma <- sqrt(2*Var)
fit <- function(f1,f2,f3,f4,f5){
    for(i in 1:n){
        for(j in 1:4){
            P <- if(x[i,j] == 1) {f1} else if(x[i,j] == 2) {f2} else if(x[i,j] == 3) {f3} else if(x[i,j] == 4) {f4} else   {f5}
            Q <- if(x[i,j+1] == 1) {f1} else if(x[i,(j+1)] == 2) {f2} else if(x[i,(j+1)] == 3) {f3} else if(x[i,(j+1)] == 4) {f4} else {f5}
            mu <- P-Q
            matris[i,j] <- pnorm(0,mean=mu,sd=sigma,lower.tail=FALSE,log.p=TRUE)     
        }
    }
    -sum(matris)
}
mle.results <- mle(fit,start=list(f1=a[1],f2=a[2],f3=a[3],f4=a[4],f5=a[5]))
summary(mle.results)
```

Comment: Please use `R` syntax. For example, by `x_1` do you mean `x[1]` ? You have not passed any `x` to your `fit` function, so expect disaster.  Further, based on how you created `x`, it will **never** be the case that `x[i,j]==1` is TRUE. Please read `?'=='` and `?all.equal` .

Comment: OK, sorry. Before the code it should be: y[1]>y[4]>y[5]>y[3]>y[2] not x_1>x_4>x_5>x_3>x_2 and  P(Y[1]-Y[4]>0|a)*P(Y[4]-Y[5]>0|a)*P(Y[5]-Y[3]>0|a)*P(Y[3]-Y[2]>0|a) not P(X_1-X_4>0|a)*P(X_4-X_5>0|a)*P(X_5-X_3>0|a)*P(X_3-X_2>0|a) and Y[1]-Y[4] ~ N(a[1]-a[4],2*std^2). I don't understand what you mean by "you have not passed any x to your fit function".

Comment: Inside your definition of the function, you make use of the variable `x[i,j]` but that object, `x`, is not an argument to your function. As it happens , `R` lets a function look to the parent environment, but should you ever change the object `x` there, you have no way of passing a desired object into your function. You should do `fit<-function(f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,x)`

Comment: As a side note, you might find `?switch` more convenient in the future rather writing out extensive `if else` conditions

Comment: I get the following result:
The standard errors are still "weird". Have you tried to run it?
'Maximum likelihood estimation

   Call:
   mle(minuslogl = fit, start = list(f1 = a[1], f2 = a[2], f3 = a[3], 
    f4 = a[4], f5 = a[5]), fixed = list(x = x))

    Coefficients:
    Estimate Std. Error
    f1 100.1527   8388.658
    f2 100.4711   8388.658
    f3 100.6207   8388.658
    f4 100.6025   8388.658
    f5 100.3529   8388.658

    -2 log L: 500.1681 '

Sorry that it looks weird. This is the first time I write on this page